# How to Change Reponse Acc to User Role in NestJs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend

I am learning Nestjs and having issues understanding how I can change or hide the fields while returning the data to the user.

for Exampe I have a route website.com/product/1

and the fields in the product table are title, price, category, createdBy,

when some normal user hits the API I want to hide the createdBy and when the admin or the store admin hits the API I want to return the created field also how I can achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Serialization ! See => https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization

For example you have `customer` entity and route for get one customer is `GET customer/:id`

In your controller :

```js
@Controller('customer')
export class CustomerController {

   @Get(':id/v2')
    public async getOneById(
        @Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id: number,
    ): Promise<CustomerSerializer> {
       return this.service.getOneCustomer(id);
    }

}
```

In your Service :

```js
export class CustomerService {
   public async getOneCustomer(id): Promise<CustomerSerializer> {
        // Get your customer in BDD

        if (customers.data.length !== 1) {
            throw new NotFoundException('customer not found');
        }

        return plainToInstance(CustomerSerializer, customers.data, {
                groups: defaultCustomersGroupsForSerializing,
        });
    }

}
```

And your CustomerSerializer :

```js
export const defaultCustomersGroupsForSerializing: string[] = [];

export const allCustomersGroupsForSerializing: string[] = [...defaultCustomersGroupsForSerializing, 'system'];

export class CustomerSerializer implements ICustomer {
    @Expose({ group: 'system' })
    @ApiProperty({ type: String })
    public createdBy: string;

    @Expose()
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ApiProperty()
    public legalName: string;

   // ...
}
```

The convention is to never expose an entity from a route but either a copy or a DTO or a serialize object